# What are the rules for closing prepared statements?

Tags: php, database, sqlite

I'm currently using SQLite3 class for PHP. I've noticed `SQLite3Stmt::close()` as well as `SQLite3Result::finalize()`.

Is it essential to call these functions? I'm having a bit of trouble calling them because I don't exactly know when they're no longer being used in my database wrapper class as I will have to often return a SQLite3Result

For example:

```
function execSomething(){
  $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
  return $stmt->execute();
}
```

Should you always close the prepared statement?

Comment: I think prepared statements get deallocated by the database when you close the connection, so it depends how long your connection lasts. If it dies with the end of the script, you probably don't have to bother, but if you're writing something that runs indefinitely, you should probably clean up after yourself.

Comment: I'm writing something that simplifies database interactions by cutting out the SQL writing part. So technically it dies when the webpage load, but I don't know how long it will run for.

Comment: It's your call. If you know you won't need the statement anymore, kill it. If you don't, run some profiling to see if you're getting in trouble memory-wise.

Comment: phpunit doesn't make it seem like it use a lot of memory. However IDK if there's a large volume or side effects of not closing them.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that any side effects would not live past the end of your script, so if there's no problem with it now, you can probably concentrate on something else for the time being.

Comment: I do need to focus on other things atm. I'm going to leave this open though.

Answer (score 1):

I was curious too, because for someone unfamiliar with PHP and its SQLite3 extension, the documentation doesn't make clear what these functions actually *do* (i.e., what's happening in SQLite when you call them?):

> `SQLite3Stmt::close` — Closes the prepared statement
>
> `SQLite3Result::finalize` — Closes the result set

Taking a (highly unqualified) look at the source (https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/ext/sqlite3/sqlite3.c), at the time of this writing:

`SQLite3Result::finalize`, at `PHP_METHOD(sqlite3result, finalize)`, seems to end up calling [sqlite3_reset](https://sqlite.org/c3ref/reset.html) on any associated prepared statement, as well as freeing some internal data structures.

`SQLite3Stmt::close`, at `PHP_METHOD(sqlite3stmt, close)`, seems to just end up freeing internal data structures for the statement.

Thus, as far as I can tell, it seems to be a question of managing internal  resources and of triggering calls to `sqlite3_reset`, which according to the SQLite docs:

> "...[resets] a prepared statement object back to its initial state, ready
> to be re-executed"

No comment as to what happens when your script terminates and you haven't called these, as I haven't tried to look into that.

All that said, I'm a newbie in this department and it's the first time I've cracked open the PHP source, so I'd appreciate a PHP/SQLite3 expert stepping in to correct anything wrong or misleading here.

Answer (score 0):

> I don't exactly know when they're no longer being used in my database
>   wrapper class

Can you create a [destructor](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.decon.php) on your PHP wrapper class that calls these methods? When your wrapper object is destroyed by PHP's garbage collector you'll *know* that your statements/results will no longer be used.

Comment: @zerkms, I've just made an edit to include the relevance that was in my head but not in the answer.

Comment: still is irrelevant. The main question is "Is it essential to call these functions?" Is it? Why?

Comment: Yes. That's the question, but the problem is that @ultimatebuster is having trouble calling the functions at an appropriate point in the code. So does @ultimatebuster want a solution to his problem, or an answer to his question?

Comment: well, I bet that he is not sure if it is a problem at all ;-) So am I. Not sure it is reasonable to solve something that could be not even an issue ;-)

Answer (score 0):

> I'm having a bit of trouble calling them because I don't exactly know when they're no longer being used in my database wrapper class as I will have to often return a SQLite3Result

Usually you will get a new result object every time you execute a query. This means, you should close the result set as soon as you don't need *this one* anymore.

However, you don't have to free every resource yourself, because PHP will do it for you the time the execution ends. If you don't create many many (means something around ... don't know 50?) prepared statements, I don't see a reason, why you should close them yourself.